# Unity4.6でUIのTextを複製する方法

Tags: unity3d, c#, ugui

```
public Text[] text;

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
   text[i].transform.position = new Vector3(X, Y, Z);
   Instantiate(text);   
}
```

と言った形でUnityのTextを複製しようと考えましたが、座標は確かに10個存在するものの、Textが表示されませんでした。
Unity4.6から搭載されたUIをスクリプトから生成するにはどのようにすればよろしいでしょうか？

Comment: こちら自己解決しました。
uGUIはCanvasの子要素になって初めて描画されるというアドバイスを頂いたので、CanvasとTextを両方スクリプトに実装して操作する方法にしたらうまくいきました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Textを複製する場合も結局は GameObject単位で管理することになるので、GameObjectをInstantiateするコードを書いてみました。

あと、先のコードからは、10個のTextを複製（合計20個）したいのか、1個のTextを10個複製（合計11個）したいのか分からなかったので、両方とも用意してみました。　※いずれも元となるTextはCanvasの下に既に配置済みであるという前提です。

10個のTextを複製する場合：

```
public GameObject[] text;  // インスペクタなどで事前に設定

void Start () {
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        var o = Instantiate(text[i]) as GameObject;
        o.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(X,Y,Z);
        o.transform.parent = text[i].transform.parent;  // 元のTextと同じ親にする
    }
}
```

1個のTextを10個複製する場合：

```
public GameObject originalText;  // インスペクタなどで事前に設定
GameObject[] text;

void Start () {
    text = new GameObject[10];
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        text[i] = Instantiate(originalText) as GameObject;
        text[i].transform.localPosition = new Vector3(X,Y,Z);
        text[i].transform.parent = originalText.transform.parent;  // 元のTextと同じ親にする
    }
}
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。
こちら実装しましたらうまくいきました。

Comment: このやり方で実装した場合、Textの中身をスクリプトから変更したい場合にGameObjectで管理すると
`Text.text = (string)`
が使えなくなりますが、GameObjectとして管理しているtextをTextにキャストするような方法はあったりするのでしょうか？
コンバートできないとエラーが出ます。

Comment: text[i].GetComponent<Text>().text = "string";
みたいな感じになります。

テキストを頻繁に変更する場合は、別にTextの配列を作成して事前にGetComponent<Text>()しておくとベストですが、まずは直に↑の書き方で大丈夫だと思います。

Comment: GameObject と Component（Textとか）の関係を理解しておくと今後の作業スピードでかなり差が出てきます。「スクリプトもComponentである」ということが分かるかどうかでだいぶ違ってきます。

Comment: _GameObject と Component（Textとか）の関係を理解しておくと今後の作業スピードでかなり差が出てきます。「スクリプトもComponentである」ということが分かるかど‌​うかでだいぶ違ってきます。_

ありがとうございます！
こちら参考にさせていただきます。

Answer (score 2):

uGUI の UI 要素は、Canvas の子要素でないと描画されません。
Hierarchy 上に Canvas 要素がなければ追加しましょう。

その上で、Text 要素を Canvas (またはその子要素) の子要素にする必要があります。
以下のコードを追加してみてください。

```
text[i].transform.SetParent(UnityEngine.Object.FindObjectOfType<Canvas>().transform);
```

Comment: こちらありがとうございます。

確かに`Instatiate`で複製した場合、複製された`Text`はCanvas要素がなかったために描画されておりませんでした。参考いただきましたコードを追加してみましたが、やはり複製された`Text`にCanvasの子要素なっていなかったため描画されませんでした。
描画する場合、CanvasとTextをひとまとめに複製する手順等アリますでしょうか？
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

複製されたTextのtransform.positionについては

```
transform.SetParent(ParentObject.transform, false)
```

することで、想定どおりの動作になるかもしれません。
下記のコードをScene内のオブジェクトに追加して動作させてみてください。

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TextCreator : MonoBehaviour
{
    //PanelやCanvas等、Textを配置するための親GameObjectをInspectorで設定しておく
    public GameObject ParentObject;

    //TextをPrefab化してInspectorで設定しておく
    public GameObject TextPrefab;

    // Use this for initialization
    IEnumerator Start()
    {
        var textPosition = new Vector3(10, 10);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            //TextのPrefabをInstantiate
            var obj = Instantiate(TextPrefab);

            //複製されるTextの位置を上へずらす
            obj.transform.position = textPosition + new Vector3(0, textPosition.y * i);

            //worldPositionStays=falseにすることで、TextがParentObjectによって相対的に配置される
            obj.transform.SetParent(ParentObject.transform, false);

            //1秒ごとに配置
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
        }
    }
}
```